# list index out of range when listing all projects using python-gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-api

I'm trying to use [python-gitlab](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab) to list all my gitlab projects. But when I use the following code to list part of my projects in gitlab, I got `list index out of range` error.

```py
# file name: poc.py
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(
    'http://my-gitlab.com:10080', 
    private_token='<my_private_token>'
    )
projects = gl.projects.list(all=True)
for project in projects:
    print(project.attributes['name'])
```

My gitlab server has more than 300 projects.

The following is the complete error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gitlab/__init__.py", line 783, in next
    item = self._data[self._current]
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x107784be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='my-gitlab.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v4/projects?membership=false&order_by=created_at&owned=false&page=2&per_page=20&simple=false&sort=desc&starred=false&statistics=false&with_custom_attributes=false&with_issues_enabled=false&with_merge_requests_enabled=false (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x107784be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "poc.py", line 15, in <module>
    projects = gl.projects.list(as_list=False, all=True)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gitlab/exceptions.py", line 255, in wrapped_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gitlab/mixins.py", line 133, in list
    obj = self.gitlab.http_list(path, **data)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gitlab/__init__.py", line 597, in http_list
    return list(GitlabList(self, url, query_data, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gitlab/__init__.py", line 779, in __next__
    return self.next()
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gitlab/__init__.py", line 788, in next
    self._query(self._next_url)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gitlab/__init__.py", line 716, in _query
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.pyenv/versions/3.6.5/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gitlab/__init__.py", line 498, in http_request
    result = self.session.send(prepped, timeout=timeout, **settings)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/MyUserName/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='my-gitlab.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v4/projects?membership=false&order_by=created_at&owned=false&page=2&per_page=20&simple=false&sort=desc&starred=false&statistics=false&with_custom_attributes=false&with_issues_enabled=false&with_merge_requests_enabled=false (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x107784be0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused',))
```

The error message `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='my-gitlab.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded` says that it uses port 80 instead of 10080 to communicate with gitlab server. This is because there was an `IndexError` triggered at [line 825 of gitlab/**init**.py](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/blob/master/gitlab/__init__.py#L825). So `python-gitlab` tried to use port 80 to see if this port works.

I've checked that the length of `self._data` is 20. And I don't know why `self._current` was added to `20`. `self._data[20]` triggers `IndexError` because the index's maximum value is 19.

For now, I use the following workaround to list all the projects:

```py
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(
    'http://my-gitlab.com:10080', 
    private_token='<my_private_token>'
    )

current_page = 1
projects = dest_gitlab.projects.list(as_list=False)
total_pages = projects.total_pages
while (current_page <= total_pages):
    projects = gl.projects.list(as_list=False, per_page=100, page=current_page)
    for project in projects:
        print(project.attributes['name'])
    current_page += 1
```

But this is inconvenient to list all projects.

The document [here](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-usage.html?highlight=total_pages#pagination) doesn't mention anything about this error.

Anyone know how to list all projects using `python-gitlab`?

Is this a bug of [python-gitlab](https://github.com/python-gitlab/)?

Is `len(self._data) == 20` an expected behavior when calling `gl.projects.list(all=True)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for python-gitlab using port 80 to communicate with gitlab server is because this [gitlab bug](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/issues/745).

For now, I can only use the workaround or wait for gitlab to fix this bug.

```py
import gitlab

gl = gitlab.Gitlab(
    'http://my-gitlab.com:10080', 
    private_token='<my_private_token>'
    )

current_page = 1
projects = dest_gitlab.projects.list(as_list=False)
total_pages = projects.total_pages
while (current_page <= total_pages):
    projects = gl.projects.list(as_list=False, per_page=100, page=current_page)
    for project in projects:
        print(project.attributes['name'])
    current_page += 1
```

Comment: What's the `dest_gitlab` object ? I'm trying to collect all projects but `total_pages` seems to doesn't work anymore. https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab/issues/1235